# Do I need to have played Myst in order to play Riven?

Tags: myst, riven

I finished Myst 15 years ago and I'm now ready for Riven. Do I need to remember the story of Myst to play Riven?  Or are both games are independent?

Comment: I recall that you're given a recap before beginning the adventure. Still if my memories betray me, you don't need to have played Myst to enjoy Riven. It's a great game, enjoy the puzzles!

Comment: Riven wasn't half as good as Myst if my memory serves me correctly.

Comment: @Layke Why ? It was too hard ? Too easy ? Other reasons ?

Comment: @LucM - Much harder, in my opinion, Riven was the hardest of the entire series.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are definitely connections between the plots of the two games, but you do not need to have recently played Myst to enjoy most of Riven.

That's all I can give you from memory, but feel free to do your own research online. Be wary of spoilers though!

Comment: Playing Myst and knowing the story makes for a better experience IMO but you're right that detailed memories (a recent Myst playthrough) aren't necessary.